# Ruby ActiveRecord possibly missing Methods to query SQLite

Tags: ruby, sqlite, activerecord

I am new here, and allow me to assure you that I have googled my way across the web to look for the answers to my very bothersome predicament here.  Keeping that in mind, allow me to explain:

I am running a windows system (windows 8 currently to be exact), and would like very much to write a simple program that allows a user with the aid of a GUI to save and modify certain data within a simple SQLite database.

To do this, I have installed Ruby 2.0.0 (even though Ruby 1.9.3 is suggested for Visual Ruby, but that does not even seem to remotely work when I install Visual Ruby with that version), then installed Glade 3.6.7 along with GTK+ with a one click installer.  As I mentioned, much to my surprise, Visual Ruby did not even start when I tried running it with the older Ruby version, and it does work with 2.0.0 despite a small warning.

Now comes the part where you all get to laugh at me abit, and I do feel very silly of course, but everyone has to begin somewhere.  After implementing a simple GUI, and adding a nice core that will communicate with an object that controls the querying to the database, I decided to get to work on that database connectivity.   Now at first, I wanted to use MySQL, because I quite like it, and I had worked with it in the past.  Despite any amount of Gems and Libraries I installed, I could NOT get the database connectivity to work.  So I turned to a solution that presented itself within Visual Ruby itself.... a few examples showing how ActiveRecord can be used to access a SQLite database.  They are non too specific, but after testing them and seeing that they do work, I decided to go with SQLite then.

So here I am, testing out ActiveRecord and having my first success in quite a while since this frustration began and it worked! I achieved connectivity to a database! However, success was short lived.  Allow me to show you some snippets from my code so you may better understand my problem:

---

require 'rubygems'
require 'active_record'
require 'date'

```
    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
            :adapter => "sqlite3",   
                            :database => "db/safebags.db3"
            )
```

class Safebag < ActiveRecord::Base
        self.table_name = "safebagtest"

```
def puttinRow(safeBagID, shopi, employeeName, date)
#   self.create
    self.safebagid = safeBagID
    self.datesent = date
    self.shop = shop
    self.employeesent = employeeName
    self.validness = 1
    self.save

end

def gettinValid(safeBagID)
#   safebag = self.find_by_safebagid(1)
    return 1
end
```

end

---

I know you don't see the creation of the objects here, but I assure you I do create them in my code.  I am just attempting to keep a kind of Hiarchy in my sourcode design.  Now the problems I am indeed having are with the two lines that I have marked for you with the "#".  If I keep them in my code, the program crashes as soon as they are accessed.  Allow me to show you one such example:

---

```
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activemodel-4.1.1/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:435:in `method_missing': undefined method `create' for #<Safebag:0x667cdd0>
     from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:206:in `method_missing'
     from C:/Users/Nightshade/visualruby/examples/safebags/bin/SafeBagCore.rb:168:in `puttinRow'
     from C:/Users/Nightshade/visualruby/examples/safebags/bin/SafeBagCore.rb:114:in `addSafebag'
     from C:/Users/Nightshade/visualruby/examples/safebags/bin/SafeBagCore.rb:49:in `sendSafeBag'
     from C:/Users/Nightshade/visualruby/examples/safebags/bin/MyClass.rb:19:in `eintragenButton__clicked'
     from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/vrlib-1.0.16/lib/GladeGUI.rb:173:in `call'
     from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/vrlib-1.0.16/lib/GladeGUI.rb:173:in `block (3 levels) in parse_signals'
     from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/vrlib-1.0.16/lib/GladeGUI.rb:394:in `call'
     from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/vrlib-1.0.16/lib/GladeGUI.rb:394:in `main'
     from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/vrlib-1.0.16/lib/GladeGUI.rb:394:in `show_window'
     from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/vrlib-1.0.16/lib/GladeGUI.rb:382:in `show'
     from main.rb:15:in `<main>'
```

---

You see my problem.   I read somewhere on this site that there is a possibility that Ruby 2.0.0 is not quite cut out for SQLite and that one should downgrade to 1.9.3.... HOWEVER, remember the problem I mentioned that this older version does NOT work at all with Visual Ruby.

After over a week of installing various Gems, including MySQL, MySQL2(which doesn't even install), DBI, and probably a few other things out of absolute delirium, I am clearly at my wits end.  I must be overseeing something.  If you guys could help me I would be very grateful.

Please note that if I leave both problem lines out, I CAN add a line into the database... however, if I iterate and attempt to add a second line, it simply doesn't do anything -.-

Any other methods that ActiveRecord should be able to use also end in the same result, including: find, where.

Please help me however you can.  I simply refuse to believe that Ruby is not capable of connecting and querying with a database, and I am certain that a few of you can prove to me that it does :)

-RubyJason

Comment: `create` and `find` (and the `find_by...` methods) are class-level methods, but here, you are attempting to use them in instances. I recommend reading up on [ActiveRecord](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html), and maybe go through a few more general Ruby design tutorials.

Comment: (First Question Review): Welcome. You might want to format your console error message block with the preformatted (Ctrl+k) feature to make it readable.

Comment: Formated the console error message as requested.  Thank you for the tip eckes.  I hope it is more readable now

Comment: Also..... Jebus!  I can't believe I made such a rookie mistake! @Zach Kemp, thank you so much!  I did a little research once you pointed me in the right direction, and now all I have to do is work out a few kinks and it should be up and running!  You are da bomb! In an awesomely possitive way! :D

Answer (score 0):

You can use a database.yml file if you're only doing development right now. It may serve useful later if you want to deploy your app. I'm using SQLite3 and I think if we both pursue better usage of ActiveRecord we can appreciate SQLite3
for what it is. I'm still in the process of doing things a little different than you and am able to make the database like you but my connections may need work after I figure out how to use schema.rb and migrations. I don't care about any models yet. I can use SQLite Browser which is my GUI for that db on Kali Linux. I think that you may get it for Windows also but I'm not positive. Maybe just get the source for it if you can as it may have clues for you to get your app working. Just a thought. Yep! Just found it here.
http://sqlitebrowser.org/
Good Luck!